# ConnectTimeout Error When Connecting to a ChromaDB Client that is hosted on Azure Web App

Tags: python, azure, azure-web-app-service, chromadb

When trying to connect via the client to my ChromaDB instance that is hosted on Azure Web App, I keep getting a connection timeout error

```
import chromadb

client = chromadb.HttpClient(host="https://chroma-db.azurewebsites.net")

client.list_collections()
```

```
Part of the error log includes:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
...
TimeoutError: [Errno 60] Operation timed out
...
urllib3.exceptions.ConnectTimeoutError: (<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x...>, 'Connection to chroma-db.azurewebsites.net timed out. (connect timeout=None)')
...
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='chroma-db.azurewebsites.net', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/collections (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x...>, 'Connection to my-chroma-db.azurewebsites.net timed out. (connect timeout=None)'))
...
requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: HTTPConnectionPool(host='chroma-db.azurewebsites.net', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/collections (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x...>, 'Connection to chroma-db.azurewebsites.net timed out. (connect timeout=None)'))
```

I tried adding hostname, changing the URL to include https protocol, tries different port numbers.

What changes should I make in my Azure Web App Configuration and/or in my code to connect via the client?

I'm using ChromaDB v.3.9.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also got the same error with your code in my environment.

The error might occur because of two reasons:

1. If you don't log in to your Azure account, you will get the same error.

[image]

2. If the Azure web app URL is incorrect, you will also get this error.
   So, make sure your login credentials and web app URL are correct.

[image]
[image]

I tried the below sample code to query the chromaDB with the Azure web app.

***Code*** :

```py
import chromadb
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

chroma_db_url = "https://<web_app_name>.azurewebsites.net/"

chroma_client = chromadb.Client()

collection = chroma_client.create_collection(name="my_collection")

collection.add(
    documents=["This is a document", "This is another document"],
    metadatas=[{"source": "my_source"}, {"source": "my_source"}],
    ids=["id1", "id2"]
)

query_text = "This is a query document"

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('query.html')

@app.route('/query')
def query_chromadb():
    try:
        results = collection.query(query_texts=[query_text], n_results=2)

        return jsonify(results)

    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({"error": "An error occurred while processing the query: " + str(e)})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

***templates/query.html*** :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>ChromaDB Query</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>ChromaDB Query</h1>
    <p>Click the button below to execute the predefined query:</p>
    <form method="GET" action="/query">
        <input type="submit" value="Execute Query">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

***requirements.txt*** :

```py
chromadb==0.4.12
Flask==2.0.1
requests>=2.28
```

***Output*** :

It runs successfully as shown below.

[image]

I got the below output in the browser with the above output URL, then I clicked on **Execute Query** to get the query.

[image]

I got the query output as below:

[image]

Comment: chromadb.Client() essentially creates a local instance. I figured out the way to do it if you are deployed to Web Apps is to pass the flag ssl=True and port="443" in chromadb.HttpClient() call.